# Collapse bootstrap nav bar on click in nav-items. in mobile viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar, nav

I'm a noob in bootstrap.

In simple bootstrap nav bar, I wanted it to collapse when the user clicks on the nav-item as well. so I made changes given below.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a href="#" class="nav navbar-brand">RAHUL SONI</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">Survey</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It worked as I wanted. But data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" that i have added in anchor tag also come in action when my nav-bar is in normal state.

> [My code snippet](https://www.codeply.com/go/a2Q8wxCCxJ)

Please give suggestions.

Comment: what exactly is your problem ??? i am a soni too haha

Comment: I want data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" to be work on my nav-bar items as well, but only when my nav-bar is in the collapsed state.

Comment: is the issue solved??

Comment: No, my code is working as I want but in full-width state nav-item flick on click which I want to fix

Answer (score 0):

now see your data does not toggles  is this you wanted:

```html
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- row 1 -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a href="http://www.abiworld.org" class="nav navbar-brand">RAHUL SONI</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"  data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">Survey</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No, I want it to be toggled, In my code, it is toggling, but the problem is when my nav-bar is in the full-width state and user click on the nav-item my nav-bar animate/flick in a weird manner.

Comment: its because its in toggled state that is why it flickers u yourself has given it a toggled behaviour that will happen it shows open wide  in full screen and as you have given it a toggled behaviour it will happen obviously

Comment: although you cant change the  bootstrap behaviour

Comment: Is there any way to toggle in the mobile state but not in the full-width state. because I'm using angular js to load the page content without reloading the page content and avoid unnecessary reload of CSS, js and rerender of the page.

Comment: i already said you cant change the bootstarp definition although you can use media queries for it but for that you have to design the full page in html css and use html css' nav bar and check for it